# How to fade ImageView after drag/drop is done?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have one ImageView (drag and drop) and one button that fades the Image. drag and drop works fine and fade button initially works fine to. The issue arises when the image is dragged and THEN fade button is pressed.

it seems that it only fades the original place the image was(before drag and drop). I would like to fade the actual image after its been dragged. Here is a picture explaining :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGs4C.jpg)

my main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.com.example.muhammad.downloadmanagerexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/Hello"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/images"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fade"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFade"

        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //downloadFile(path);

        image.setOnTouchListener(this);



        Button fadeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFade);
        fadeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                image.startAnimation(animation);

                //appIcon.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1000);
                //appIcon.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(1000);
            }
        });

    }

    PointF DownPT = new PointF(); // Record Mouse Position When Pressed Down
    PointF StartPT = new PointF(); // Record Start Position of 'img'

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int eid = event.getAction();
        switch (eid)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                PointF mv = new PointF( event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                image.setX((int)(StartPT.x+mv.x));
                image.setY((int)(StartPT.y+mv.y));
                StartPT = new PointF( image.getX(), image.getY() );
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                DownPT.x = event.getX();
                DownPT.y = event.getY();
                StartPT = new PointF( image.getX(), image.getY() );
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                // Nothing have to do
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have been searching about this topic and couldn't find an excat solution so thought about asking it. Thank you in advance. really appreciate this site and all of the people who contribute to it :)

Comment: you actually create new image every time.You are not dealing with one image only.You do not have same instance of image.when you fade you are deleting image.And when you drop image after dragging then you recreate image.If you find my answer appropriate then upvote me.Thanks

Comment: Sorry dude, i dont have option to upvote...i think my reputation is not there yet. Your answer helps me undertsnad the issue better...now whats the solution lol

Comment: @sakshamagarwal if you wish to be upvoted/downvoted, post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually create new image every time.You are not dealing with one image only.**You do not have same instance of image**.when you fade you are deleting image.**And when you drop image after dragging then you recreate image**.If you find my answer appropriate then upvote me.Thanks